# How to insert dropdown selected text in databse in MVC using formcollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to store a text value from a dropdown box in the Database, however I cannot do it.

My code is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMachine(FormCollection fc, HttpPostedFileBase file) {
 admachinecat();

 //admachinesubcat();
 ad.machinetype = fc["Drop"];
 ad.machinesubtype = fc["sDrop"];
 ad.machinesub_subtype = fc["subDrop"];

 ad.modelnum = fc["modelnum"];
 ad.menufacture = fc["Manufacturer"];
 ad.manufacturecat = fc["modelcat"];
 ad.File = file;
 ad.productspec = fc["product_speci"];
 ad.productdetail = fc["Editor1"];

 if (ModelState.IsValid) {
  int result = dab.admachine(ad);
  ViewData["result"] = result;
  ModelState.Clear();

  return View();
 } else {
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "error in saving data");
  return View();
 } 
}


public void admachinecat() {

  DataSet ds = dab.subcatdropdown();
  ViewBag.menulist = ds.Tables[0];
  List < SelectListItem > branchitems = new List < SelectListItem > ();
  branchitems.Add(new SelectListItem {
   Text = "---select---",
    Value = "0",
  });
  foreach(DataRow dr in ViewBag.menulist.Rows) {
   branchitems.Add(new SelectListItem {
    Text = @dr["Category_Name"].ToString(), Value = @dr["Category_Id"].ToString()
   });
  }
  ViewBag.Drop = branchitems;
}
```

In Database access layer:

```
public DataSet subcatdropdown()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Category_Id,Category_Name from Category", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

In HTML page:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">@Html.DropDownList("Drop")</div>
```

Comment: completely remade your question. Please read our community rules next time before posting ! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of form collection it would be better if you use model.Any how you can do it by using hidden helper..
Try to use jquery to fetch that text like below..

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#SelectedCategoryId').change(function () {
var SelectedCategory = $('#SelectedCategoryId option:selected').text();
          $('#hiddenStateId').val(SelectedCategory);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Html :

```
@Html.DropDownList("Drop",new { id = "SelectedCategoryId")
@Html.Hidden("SelectedCategory", new { id = "hiddenStateId" })
```

Now call SelectedCategory in controller using fc

```
ad.category = fc["SelectedCategory"];
```

Comment: @vishalgoyal..you are welcome..:).if it helped you please mark it as answer so that it will help others..